# why jquery takes same ID from WordPress shortcode if accessed multiple times?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

I have created a shortcode which generates a jquery product card with sliding options.

I want to include this in a wordpress plugin so it can be called by a wp shortcode. I did that successfully, however the issue I am facing is, when I add the shortcode twice on the same page, it won't pass the new ID. I am supplying the unique ID in shortcode itself. pls see the quick function to generate shortcode

```
function procard($atts) {
$wm_atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'id' => 1,        
        ), $atts);

$wce_uid = $atts['id'];

wp_enqueue_script('wce_reg_script' . $wce_uid, plugins_url('js/wce_script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
$data_array = array(
    'wce_id' => $wce_uid,        
);
wp_localize_script('wce_reg_script' . $wce_uid, 'data_object_name', $data_array);

$wc_output = '';
$wc_output .= '<div class="card">I removed all html for now</div>';
return $wc_output;
unset($data_array);
}

add_shortcode('procard', 'procard');
```

And here is the wce_script.js file which is enqueued.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

alert("The ID is "+ data_object_name.wce_id)
});
```

When the shortcode is present twice with ID 1 & 2, the alert will show twice with ID 2 only. it won't bring ID 1. Because of the first shortcode doesn't pass the correct data because of the unique ID.

any ideas?

Comment: paste us this element `data_object_name.wce_id`,, is that some ID on page?

Comment: If you see wp_localize_script in the php function, its sending that value to jquery

Comment: you have to call `wp_localize_script` only once in your plugin, and to be included only once.. then on page when you alert ID I think will be fine

Comment: The issue is jquery needs to update some css classes and if shortcode is executed twice on same page, jquery needs the other instance with unique class name

Comment: can you add your html page to your question,, you can paste it here or on pastebin and share here,, also what should your jquery do with that on client side

Comment: you mean I should paste the generated html? it comes messed up if shortcode is called twice. only 2nd instance works.

Comment: please paste it, that shoul help sure